# triple integral square pyramid

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

The pyramid has the base on the xy plane;
vertices $(\pm 1,0,0), (0,\pm 1,0),(0,0,1)$

So basically, with my integration limits I thought I was calculating the volume of $\frac14$ of the pyramid when I actually calculated $\frac12$, I need help figuring out why.

So I took the xy positive quadrant, sketched it and integrated with limits:
0 to (-z+1) dx
then 0 to (-z+1) dy,
then 0 to 1 dz

Why does this represent a half of the pyramid?

Comment: Seems to understand ($0$ to $1$ dz) that you considered just one face, while, on the first quadrant, the pyramid has two faces. You shall work on the first octant.

Comment: @GCab i meant to say that i considered and sketched the part of the pyramid in x>0, y>0, z>0

Comment: yes, but there is a hedge along $x=y$, did you consider that ? can you show your integral formula ?

Comment: Why do people set these wretched questions to which the answer is obvious without any integration?

Comment: @almagest practicing multiple integration...

Comment: @GCab well i read paul's notes on this and managed to do the integral, and a way to solve simmilar problems.

i should integrate dz with the plane (face of the pyramid) as an upper limit, then dy as normal in the xy plane then dx from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I realize now that the base of your pyramid is rhombic, not square (vertices at ..): so my previous comment does not apply.
Well, being the base rhombic, its section at $z$=const. is also rhombic, that is, in the $1$st quadrant, a triangle with sides $(1-z)$ and diagonal $x+y=1-z$. So its area is half than if you integrate $x$ and $y$ from $0$ to $1-z$.